# Update Parent entity without updating child entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have parent and child entity. Now when I change something in parent entity keeping child entity intact, and then when I update in the same session, I observed that it updating the updated fields in the parent entity and also all the child entity.  How to update all the updated fields and not whole inheritance tree.

Comment: Are you talking about [dirty checking](https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/08/21/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/)? It really shouldn't update all the fields.

Comment: Yes, Its updating all the fields of child entities. The scenario is expected when  I create and update the entity in the same session, as it only updates the delta. But when I use to get the entity, modify few properties of the parent entity and then when i commit the transaction, it updates the parent entity with the changed column plus it updates all the columns of the child entities.

Comment: Edit your question and include the relevant portions of the code, as well as the code for your entities.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Cascading Options](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade) that you can set in the child association mapping. This is the way that JPA allows you to propagate the state transition from a parent entity to a child.

Comment: Cascade doesn't mean "update the child entity even though nothing is changed". This doesn't solve the situation where you want to avoid unwarranted updates to child entity.

Comment: I didn't claim that neither it seems to be @BigBang's question. Neither i think the question is about "unwarranted updates to child entity". It's about unwanted cascaded changes started from the parent

Comment: Reading his comment, it seems that it's exactly what he's talking about. Not about cascading.

Comment: Ah they might have added it after I saw this for the last time. I'll leave this here until @BigBang adds some code as you are suggesting. It's a lot of guesswork otherwise